# How to add a redirection at the end of Delete entity process?

Tags: 8, forms, entities

I used Drupal Console to create a custom content entity called 'Service' (with command `drupal geco`) which generated all expected code including 'ServiceDeleteForm.php':

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\sel\Form;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityDeleteForm;
/**
 * Provides a form for deleting Service category entities.
 *
 * @ingroup sel
 */
class ServiceDeleteForm extends ContentEntityDeleteForm {
}
```

I added some code of mine there:

```
class ServiceDeleteForm extends ContentEntityDeleteForm {

  protected function getDeletionMessage() {
    $entity = $this->getEntity();
    drupal_set_message($this->t('Le service « %label » a été supprimé.', [
      '%label' => $entity->label(),
    ]));
  }

  public function getQuestion() {
    return $this->t('Êtes-vous certain de vouloir supprimer le service « %label » ?', [
      '%label' => $this->getEntity()->label(),
    ]);
  }

}
```

which works fine.
I'd like to add a redirection at the end of the Delete process, something like  `$form_state->setRedirect('elsewhere', [some argument]);`
but I don't know how to do it.
Could someone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, this code works:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\sel\Form;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityDeleteForm;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Provides a form for deleting Service entities.
 *
 * @ingroup sel
 */

class ServiceDeleteForm extends ContentEntityDeleteForm {

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $entity = $this->getEntity();

    $entity->delete();
    $form_state->setRedirect('elsewhere', [some argument]);
    drupal_set_message($this->getDeletionMessage());

  }

  protected function getDeletionMessage() { some code }

  public function getQuestion() { some code }

}
```